# Get non-null elements in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` and I want to get some non-null elements as a list.

Specifically, given `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["A",None,"B"],"b":[None,"C","D"],"c":["E","F",None]})
      a     b     c
0     A  None     E
1  None     C     F
2     B     D  None
```

and the interesting columns list `["a","c"]`, I want to extract the list of non-`None` element of the specified columns, i.e.,

```
["A","B","E","F"]
```

I guess I can do

```
[value for colname in interesting_columns
 for value in df.loc[df[colname].notnull(),colname]]
```

but I was wondering if there is some non-iterative magic trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) it to long format and retrieve the data with `.values` accessor. By default, `stack()` drops missing values automatically:

```
df[['a', 'c']].T.stack().values
# array(['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], dtype=object)
```

---

Or if you want a list:

```
df[['a', 'c']].T.stack().tolist()
# ['A', 'B', 'E', 'F']
```

---

[`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) is needed to get the values in the order you requested.