# How to read unicode from CSV into DataFrame

Tags: csv, pandas, unicode

When I read a CSV file using [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), I get this string:

```
'_\xf4\xd6_'
```

which I cannot normalize (drop non-ASCII characters):

```
>>> '_\xf4\xd6_'.encode("ascii","ignore")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What I want is:

```
>>> u'_\xf4\xd6_'.encode("ascii","ignore")
'__'
```

IOW, I need to **either**

- tell `pandas.read_csv` to read strings as unicode or
- somehow convert `str` to `unicode` myself.

**How do I do that?**

PS. For completeness, here is the code (see [Get non-null elements in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41705388/850781)):

```
import pandas as pd

def normalize(s):
    "Clean-up the string: drop non-ASCII, normalize whitespace."
    return re.sub(r"\s+"," ",s,flags=re.UNICODE).encode("ascii","ignore")

df = pd.read_csv("foo.csv",low_memory=False)
my_strings = [normalize(s) for s in df[my_cols].stack.tolist()]
```

PPS. I have no control over the content of the CSV file (i.e., I cannot solve the problem by writing the CSV file "correctly").

Answer (score 0):

Here is a replacement `normalize` using [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
def drop_non_ascii(s):
    if type(s) == unicode:
        return s.encode("ascii",errors="ignore")
    return bytearray(s).decode("ascii",errors="ignore")

def normalize(s):
    "Clean-up the string: drop non-ASCII, normalize whitespace."
    return drop_non_ascii(re.sub(r"\s+"," ",s,flags=re.UNICODE))
```

Is this the right solution?