# How to retrieve cells from a dataframe based on condition from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

We have two dataframes, first one contains some float values (which mean average speed).

```
                 0          1          2      
1           15.610826  19.182879   6.678087  
2           13.740250  15.666897   17.640749
3           2.379010   2.889702    2.955097 
4           20.540628   9.661226   9.479921
```

And another dataframe with geographical coordinates, where the average speed takes place.

```
                  0                                  1                              2
1         [52.2399255, 21.0654495]           [52.23893150000001, 21.06087]    [52.23800850000001,21.056779]
2         [52.2449705, 21.0755175]           [52.2452905, 21.075118000000003]   [52.245557500000004, 21.0748175]
3         [52.2401885, 21.012981500000002]   [52.239134, 21.009432]             [52.238420500000004, 21.007080000000002]
4         [52.221506500000004, 20.9665085]   [52.222458, 20.968952]             [52.224409, 20.969248999999998]
```

Now I want to create a list with coordinates where average speed is above 18, in this case this would be

```
list_above_18=[[52.23893150000001, 21.06087] , [52.221506500000004, 20.9665085]]
```

How can I select values from a dataframe based on values in another dataframe?

Comment: There is no way for me to test anything here since you haven't provided enough code, but you can try creating masks like so; `mask = df1.loc[:, 0] > 18`, and then using them to filter your dataframes like so; `df2.loc[mask, 0]`. This is just a mask for the 0th column.

Comment: You should avoid loop especially in case of pandas and numpy. Vecotorise wherever possible as it would be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use enumerate to zip the dataframes and work on the elements seperately. See below (A,B are your dataframes, in same order you provided them):

```
list_above_18=[]
p=list(enumerate(zip(A.values, B.values)))

for i in p:
    for k in range(3):
        if i[1][0][k]>18:
            list_above_18.append(i[1][1][k])
```

Output:

```
>>>print(list_above_18)

[[52.23893150000001, 21.06087] , [52.221506500000004, 20.9665085]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the shape of the Average Speed dataset will remain same as the coordinates dataset, you can try the below

```
coord_df[data_df.iloc[:,:] > 18].T.stack().values
```

Here,
coord_df = DataFrame with coordinate values
data_df = Average Speed values

This would return a numpy array with just the coordinate values where the Average speed is greater than 18

How this works :

```
data_df.iloc[:,:] > 18
```

Creates a dataframe mask such that all the values which are smaller than 18 are marked as False and rest as True

```
coord_df[data_df.iloc[:,:] > 18]
```

Passes the mask in the Target Dataframe i.e. coordinate dataframe which then results in a dataframe which shows coordinate values only for those cells where the mask has True i.e. where the average speed was above 18

```
.T.stack().values
```

This then retrieves only the non-null values from the resultant dataframe and returns a numpy array

References I took :

1. [Get non-null elements in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41705388/get-non-null-elements-in-a-pandas-dataframe) --- To get only the non null values from a dataframe (.T.stack().values)

Answer (score 1):

Let the first df be df1 and second df be df2

```
output_array = df2[df1>18].values.flatten() # df1>18 would create the mask
output_array = [val for val in output_array if type(val) == list] # removing the nan values. We can't use np.isnan as it would not work for list
```

Sample Input:

df1

[image]

df2

[image]

output_array

[[15.1, 20.5], [91.5, 95.8]]